# Sed block garbled on tcsh. Works in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, tcsh

I have a working sed command that replaces some coordinates in the **matched** block as seen below:
The sed command looks like this and works in the **bash**:

```
sed '/^matched.*$/ {
n;n;n;s/img{[0-9]*,[0-9]*}/img{0,10}/;n;s/img{[0-9]*,[0-9]*}/img{20,30}/;n;s/img{[0-9]*,[0-9]*}/img{40,0}/ 
}
' file.txt
```

It searches for a match and performs some **s**ubstitutions in the **n**ext lines 
The problem is that contrary to the bash, if I type the first line of code and hit Enter in **tcsh**. The code gets executed immediately and returns missing '. 
If I execute the same command with **tcsh** and remove all the linebreaks then I get **sed: command garbled:** (With bash sed version 4.2.2 on ubuntu it even works without newlines)

I know that the problem has to do with the new lines before and after the curly brackets { } that contain the block of sed code. But I don't know how to enter them there. 
Also, I do not know how I would put those newline characters in a shell script to have the curly brackets on their separate lines.

**file.txt:**

```
unmatched
                                           {
                                             "img{170,68}"
                                             "img{817,252}"
                                             "img{664,1096}"
                                             "img{12,943}"
                                           }

matched
                                           {
                                             "img{0,0}"
                                             "img{0,111}"
                                             "img{222,333}"
                                             "img{444,0}"
                                           }
```

Answer (score 2):

`tcsh` is a syntactic heir of `csh` and as such, requires that any broken lines inside of either `'...single-quotes...'` or `"...dbl-quotes..."` be escaped with the `\` character.

So you want

```
sed '/^matched.*$/ { \
n;n;n;s/img{[0-9]*,[0-9]*}/img{0,10}/;n;s/img{[0-9]*,[0-9]*}/img{20,30}/;n;s/img{[0-9]*,[0-9]*}/img{40,0}/ \
} \
' file.txt
```

Note also that the `\` char must be the last character on the line; any white space characters following will generate an equally mysterious error message :-)

(I don't have a `[t]csh' environment available to me now, so I can' test this answer as I would normally do.)

IHTH